# Fill the blank to make a true identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

I need to make a true identity by filling the missing part here:
 $$C\setminus(A\triangle B) = (A\cap C)\triangle ...................$$

I used Venn diagrams to find a solution which led me to $(A\cap C)\triangle(C\setminus B)$, however when I tried to represent what it means for x to be an element of both sides of the solution. Both answer differs, or I missing something. Here is what I have done:

For $x$ to be an element of $C\setminus(A\triangle B)$, means:
$$(x\in C\setminus x\in((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))) - \text{definition of }\triangle
\\
(x\in C\land\neg((x\in A\land x\notin B)\cup(x\in B\land x\notin A))) -\text{definition of }\setminus\\(x\in C\land\neg(x\in A\land x\notin B)\lor(x\in B\land x\notin A)) - \text{definition of }\cup\\(x\in C\land(\neg(x\in A\land x\notin B)\land \neg(x\in B\land x\notin A))) - \text{DeMorgan's law}\\(x\in C\land((x\notin A\lor x\in B)\land(x\notin B\lor x\in A)))-\text{DeMorgan's law}\\
\text{after associative law I end up  with }  x\in C\land(x\notin A\lor x\in B)\land(x\notin B\lor x\in A)$$

The right side $(A\cap C)\triangle(C\setminus B):$
$$((A\cap C)\setminus(C\setminus B))\cup((C\setminus B)\setminus(A\cap C)) \text{ means:}\\ ((x\in A\land x\in C)\setminus x\in(C\setminus B))\cup(x\in(C\setminus B)\setminus(x\in A\land x\in C))-\text{definition of }\cap\\((x\in A\land x\in C)\land\neg(x\in C\land x\notin B))\cup((x\in C\land x\notin B)\land\neg(x\in A\land x\in C))- \text{definition}\ \setminus\\((x\in A\land x\in C)\land\neg(x\in C\land x\notin B))\cup((x\in C\land x\notin B)\land\neg(x\in A\land x\in C))-\text{definition}\ \cup\\((x\in A\land x\in C)\land(x\notin C\lor x\in B))\lor((x\in C\land x\notin B)\land(x\notin A\lor x\notin C))-\text{DeMorgan's\ law}\\(x\in A\land (x\in C\land(x\notin C\lor x\in B))\lor((x\in C\land x\notin B)\land(x\notin A\lor x\notin C))-\text{associative law} \\(x\in A\land ((x\in C\land x\notin C)\lor (x\in C\land x\in B))\lor((x\in C\land x\notin B)\land(x\notin A\lor x\notin C))-\text{distributive law}\\(x\in A\land (x\in C\land x\in B))\lor((x\in C\land x\notin B)\land(x\notin A\lor x\notin C))-\text{contradiction law}\\(x\in A\land (x\in C\land x\in B))\lor( x\notin B\land(x\in C\land(x\notin A\lor x\notin C)))-\text{associative law}\\(x\in A\land (x\in C\land x\in B))\lor( x\notin B\land((x\in C\land x\notin A)\lor (x\in C\land x\notin C)))-\text{distributive law}\\(x\in A\land (x\in C\land x\in B))\lor( x\notin B\land(x\in C\land x\notin A))-\text{contradiction law}\\(x\in A\land x\in C\land x\in B)\lor( x\notin B\land x\in C\land x\notin A)-\text{associative law}\\x\in C\land ((x\in A\land x\in B)\lor( x\notin B\land x\notin A))$$

Sorry for being so verbose here. The question is are those results correct? If not - what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: I do have $(A\cap C)$ given for the right side.

Comment: The two results are not the same.  $A\cap B\cap C$ is a subset of the right-hand side (look at at the last line of your calculation of the right-hand side) but not of the left-hand-side (again, look at the last line of your calculation of the left-hand side.)

Comment: However, an element of $A\cap B\cap C$ is an element of $C\setminus(A\triangle B)$ so there's a mistake in your calculation of the left-hand side.

Comment: I looks like something isn't right in the left-hand side calculation indeed. I have represented it like the $C\setminus(A\triangle B) = ((A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$. Here is the complete calculation:
$$$$

Comment: $$x\in C\land\neg((x\in A\cup x\in B)\land \neg(x\in A\cap x\in B))-definition\ \setminus\\x\in C\land\neg((x\in A\lor x\in B)\land \neg(x\in A\cap x\in B))-definition\ \cup\\x\in C\land\neg((x\in A\lor x\in B)\land \neg(x\in A\land x\in B))-definition\ \cap\\x\in C\land(\neg(x\in A\lor x\in B)\lor \neg\neg(x\in A\land x\in B))-DeMorgan's\ law\\x\in C\land(\neg(x\in A\lor x\in B)\lor (x\in A\land x\in B))-double\ negation\ law\\x\in C\land((x\notin A\land x\notin B)\lor (x\in A\land x\in B))-DeMorgan's\ law$$ Which is twisting my mind - where is my misstake in the initial calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any error in the calculations in the OP. It is true that $C \smallsetminus (A \triangle B) = (A \cap C) \triangle (C \smallsetminus B)$, in particular $A \cap B \cap C$ is included in both the right-hand and left-hand sides.

As you correctly derived in the OP, $x \in C \smallsetminus (A \triangle B)$ is equivalent to 
\begin{align}\tag{1}
x\in C\land (x\notin A\lor x\in B)\land(x\notin B\lor x\in A),
\end{align}
whereas $x \in (A \cap C) \triangle (C \smallsetminus B)$ is equivalent to 
\begin{align}\tag{2}
x \in C\land ((x\in A\land x\in B)\lor( x\notin B\land x\notin A)).
\end{align}

We need to show that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$. Clearly, it is enough to prove that $(x\notin A\lor x\in B)\land(x\notin B\lor x\in A)$ and $(x\in A\land x\in B)\lor( x\notin B\land x\notin A)$ are equivalent.

\begin{align}
&(x\notin A\lor x\in B) \land (x\notin B\lor x\in A) \\
\iff& (x\notin B\lor x\in A) \land (x\notin A\lor x\in B) &\text{commutativity} \\
\iff& \big((x \in A \lor x \notin B) \land (x\in B \lor x \notin B)\big) \land \big((x \in A \lor x \notin A) \land (x\in B \lor x \notin A)\big)&\text{tautology added in }\land \\
\iff& \big((x \in A \land x\in B) \lor x \notin B\big) \land \big((x \in A \land x\in B) \lor x \notin A\big)&\text{distributivity} \\
\iff& (x\in A\land x\in B) \lor (x\notin B\land x\notin A) &\text{distributivity}
\end{align}

Comment: Awesome. I didn't thought adding a tautology can be an option. Thanks.

Comment: @Dimitar - In general, if $\top$ is a tautology, then $A \land \top \iff A$; also, if $\bot$ is a contradiction then $A \lor \bot \iff A$.